# Data does not populate in the UITableView as subview of root view

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have one MainViewController and one `UITableViewController`. I called `UITableViewController` to add sub view of MainViewConroller by using Custom Segment.When i tested `UITableViewController` independently, everything is working fine and data is populated in `UITableView` successfully. When i called from MainViewController,the Data is not being populated in `UITableView`. What's wrong with my approach? This is done by following code.

*CustomTabBarSegue.m*

```
#import "CustomTabBarSegue.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarSegue

-(void)perform{
    MainViewController *rootVC = (MainViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;
    for(UIView *view in rootVC.placeholder.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    rootVC.currentViewController = dst;
    [rootVC.placeholder addSubview:dst.view];
}
```

*ListingViewConroller.m*

```
#import "ListingViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@interface ListingViewController ()
@end

@implementation ListingViewController

@synthesize jobs;
@synthesize jobDictionary;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self makeOperationRequest];
}

-(void)makeOperationRequest
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/api/jobs"]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
        jobDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        jobs = [jobDictionary objectForKey:@"jobs"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error:%@,%@",error,error.userInfo);
    }];
    [operation start];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return jobs.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
    cell.textLabel.text = [[jobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CustomerName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[jobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Address"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Remember just for safety to reloadData on the main thread

Comment: Tell me how ur adding/calling ur tableviewcontroller from mainviewcontroler?..if any chance paste the code too...and how ur loading the tableview?

Comment: Your custom segue looks fishy. Why add the detail controller's view to the root vc? Why even subclass segue? Try this with a standard segue and set the parameters in `prepareForSegue` as usual.

Comment: i just made CustomTabBar at the mainviewcontroller, there are two button at that tab bar. and just link with segue that button and uitableviewcontroller. @PKCoder you can check in this link https://gist.github.com/bochan/2b61da7e72e21c565c49

Comment: Oh dear,u r messing it up...have a look at the Phil Ringsmuth and paul's comments/suggestion here ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083481/iphone-self-performseguewithidentifier-is-not-showing-the-new-view-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reload the table view after adding it as subview.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

May it can solve ur issue.